# VoltDB - decimal values have too many zeroes

Tags: java, sql, voltdb

when I try to add a decimal value to a column in voltdb, it always adds extra zeroes to the decimal.  The column type is DECIMAL, which equates to Java's BigDecimal type.  Even if I format the BigDecimal value in java to a two decimal place BigDecimal before doing the insert, it still shows up with lots of trailing zeroes in the column.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged "sql"?

Comment: Because maybe it's a general SQL issue that someone might know how to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DECIMAL columns in VoltDB are stored as 16-bytes with a fixed scale of 12 and precision of 38.  The range of values is from -99999999999999999999999999.999999999999 to 99999999999999999999999999.999999999999.

When you say "it still shows up with lots of trailing zeros" you may be seeing the way one of the interfaces displays DECIMAL values by default.  You can control formatting in your own client in various ways depending on what language you are using.  You may also used the [FORMAT_CURRENCY()](http://docs.voltdb.com/UsingVoltDB/sqlfuncformatcurrency.php) SQL function to convert a DECIMAL value to a string representation with a given number of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks Ben, didn't know you were here too!